# rails grape-entity present is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I am trying to use grape-entity with no luck, I am using together with dry-mondads

Inside my entity I have the following code

```
module Entities
  module Test
    class Show < Grape::Entity
      expose :id
    end
  end
end
```

in my endpoint I have the following code

```
 transaction.call do |m|
   m.success do |bank_process|
     hs = { id: 'test' }
     present hs, with: ::Entities::Test::Show
   end
```

The call on `present hs, with: ::Entities::Test::Show` returns the string representation of the object `:Entities::Test::Show` => `<Entities::Test::Show:0x00007f03649ceff0>`